# class scope question in PHP

Tags: php, class, scope

scope issue in PHP classes:

Why does this work?

```
 class index extends Application
  {
        function ShowPage()
        {
            $smarty = new Smarty();         // construct class
            $smarty->assign('name', 'Ned');     // then call a method of class
            $smarty->display('index.tpl');
        }   

}
```

$index_instance = new index;
$index_instance->ShowPage();

but this does not work?

```
class index extends Application
{

    function ShowPage()
    {

        $smarty->assign('name', 'Ned');
        $smarty->display('index.tpl');
    }   
}

$index_instance = new index;
$smarty = new Smarty();
$index_instance->ShowPage();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of PHP variable scoping.

Functions *and methods* don't see any variables defined outside of them.  You have to use the `global` keyword to declare that you want access to variables defined outside of the function scope.

This won't work:

```
class Foo {
    public function bar() {
        echo $baz;
    }
}
$f = new Foo();
$baz = 'Hello world!';
$f->bar(); // "Notice: Undefined variable: ..."
```

This *will* work:

```
class Foo2 {
    public function bar() {
        global $baz; // <- "I want $baz from the global scope"
        echo $baz;
    }
}
$f = new Foo2();
$baz = 'Hello world!';
$f->bar(); // "Hello world!"
```

Even though it works, you should avoid using it.  There are better ways to go about passing in external object.  One way is called "[dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection.)", which is a fancy way of saying "pass in external dependencies during construction."  For example:

```
class Index extends Application {
    private $smarty;
    public function __construct(Smarty $smarty) {
        $this->smarty = $smarty;
    }
    public function showPage() {
        $smarty->assign('foo', 'bar');
        $smarty->display('index.tpl');
    }
}
$sm = new Smarty(...);
$whatever = new Index($sm);
$whatever->showPage();
```

Another way is using a registry, which is a pattern used to store things that otherwise might be global variables.  Let's try out [Zend Registry](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.using.html) as an example.

```
class Index extends Application {
    public function showPage() {
        $smarty = Zend_Registry::get('smarty');
        $smarty->assign('foo', 'bar');
        $smarty->display('index.tpl');
    }
}
$sm = new Smarty(...);
Zend_Registry::set('smarty', $sm);
$whatever = new Index();
$whatever->showPage();
```

Comment: `global` isn't for variables from the previous scope, but from the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: because $smarty doesn't exist within the scope of $index_instance.

If you want to instantiate a new Smarty outside of your index class, then you need to pass the smarty to the index instance:

```
class index extends Application 
{ 
    private $smarty = null;

    function __construct($smarty) {
        $this->smarty = $smarty;
    }

    function ShowPage() 
    { 

        $this->smarty->assign('name', 'Ned'); 
        $this->smarty->display('index.tpl'); 
    }    
} 

$smarty = new Smarty(); 
$index_instance = new index($smarty); 
$index_instance->ShowPage();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am now using *dependency injection* method.

```
require_once("/classes/Conf.php");
require_once("/classes/Application.php");

class index extends Application
{
    private $template_instance;

    public function __construct(Smarty $template_instance)
    {
        $this->template_instance = $template_instance;
    }

    function ShowPage()
    {
        $this->template_instance->assign('name', 'Ned'); 
        $this->template_instance->display('index.tpl'); 
    }   
}

$template_instance = new Smarty();
$index_instance = new Index($template_instance);
$index_instance->showPage();
```